# Update Table with DISTINCT SELECTed values from same TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

[image]

What I want to do is that Select the `attr_id` WHERE a DISTINCT `name_en-GB` appears and then SET that selected `attr_id` for that `name_en-GB`

I can do this by writing individual queries but I want to know is there any way I can do this in one query?

I have tried this

```
UPDATE sc_product_phrase
SET attr_id = (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        sc_product_phrase.caption,
        sc_product_phrase.design_phrase_id
    FROM
        `sc_product_phrase` as x
    GROUP BY
        sc_product_phrase.caption
    )
```

but this show error

> [Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 'sc_product_phrase' for
> update in FROM clause

**EDITED**

I want my TABLE to look like the following http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d65eb/1

NOTE:- I dont want to use that query in that fiddle

Comment: Please edit you question and show what you want the data to look like *after* the update.  Also, your query includes columns, such as `caption`, that are not in the sample data.  Please fix the question.

Comment: You are trying to set the value of one field to the value of two fields.  That will never work.

Comment: If I do not do 

`SELECT DISTINCT
  sc_product_phrase.caption`

Then i dont get DISTINCT `caption`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL Fiddle makes the question much clearer.  You want the minimum attribute id on all rows with the same value in the last column.  You can do this with an `update`/`join` like this:

```
UPDATE table1 JOIN
       (SELECT `name_en-GB`, min(Attr_Id) as minai
        from table1
        GROUP BY `name_en-GB`
       ) tt
       on table1.`name_en-GB` = tt.`name_en-GB`
   SET attr_id = tt.minai
 WHERE table1.`name_en-GB` IN ('Bride Name', 'Child Grade') AND
       table1.attr_id <> tt.minai;
```

I'm not sure if you need the `in` part.  You can update all of them by removing that clause.